# Additional "Or-Criteria" in the ON-Clause of an inner join

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, join

What is the correct way to (inner-)join two tables when the `On-Clause-Criteria` depends on either of two columns? So Table1 should join when either one of two columns is equal to one column of Table2.

Have a look at the following simplified T-SQL to see what i mean and if i'd done it in the correct way:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO
create table #RMA1(
    SSN_IN varchar(15),
    SSN_OUT varchar(15)
)
create table #RMA2(
    SSN_NUMBER varchar(15),
)
INSERT INTO #RMA1 VALUES('012590001827977', '351600035840752');
INSERT INTO #RMA1 VALUES('332653577440220', '351600035804105');
INSERT INTO #RMA1 VALUES('350302031074780', '350302031074780');
INSERT INTO #RMA1 VALUES('351649036778024', '351806033440194');

INSERT INTO #RMA2 VALUES('012590001827977');
INSERT INTO #RMA2 VALUES('332653577440220');
INSERT INTO #RMA2 VALUES('350302031074780');
INSERT INTO #RMA2 VALUES('351649036778024');
INSERT INTO #RMA2 VALUES('351600035840752');
INSERT INTO #RMA2 VALUES('351600035804106');

SELECT SSN_IN,SSN_OUT,SSN_NUMBER FROM #RMA1 INNER JOIN
#RMA2 ON (#RMA1.SSN_IN = #RMA2.SSN_NUMBER OR
          #RMA1.SSN_Out = #RMA2.SSN_NUMBER)

DROP TABLE #RMA1;
DROP TABLE #RMA2;
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Result:

```
SSN_IN          SSN_OUT            SSN_NUMBER
012590001827977 351600035840752    012590001827977
012590001827977 351600035840752    351600035840752
332653577440220 351600035804105    332653577440220
350302031074780 350302031074780    350302031074780
351649036778024 351806033440194    351649036778024
```

**Q:** So is it correct to join the tables with an `OR` in the `ON`-Clause of the inner join?

It does correctly return 5 records and drops the last record of #RM2 because it's neither in `#RM1.SSN_IN` nor in `#RM1.SSN_OUT`. But i'm feeling bad that this does not always gives the correct result. Actually the real complete query's performance is very poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result should be correct, but your observation is correct that the performance is bad. The database can't use indexes efficiently as it has to scan the index and do an arithmetic operation for each item.

Making two left joins instead would let the database make better use of indexes:

```
select
  SSN_IN,
  SSN_OUT,
  coalesce(T1.SSN_NUMBER, T2.SSN_NUMBER) as SSN_NUMBER
from
  #RMA1
  left join #RMA2 as T1 on #RMA1.SSN_IN = T1.SSN_NUMBER
  left join #RMA2 as T2 on #RMA1.SSN_Out = T2.SSN_NUMBER
where
  T1.SSN_NUMBER is not null or T2.SSN_NUMBER is not null
```